# On what Stack Exchange site should one post a question about asking feedback regarding a flowchart about software?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

A flowchart has been created in order to describe the process of software that has to be created. As it is my first software flowchart I would like to get feedback, but I do not know exactly what Stack Exchange site is the most suitable for it.

The flowchart will describe the process of the application, i.e., a UI has to be opened, login, data needs to be entered and the user should be logged out. How much detail is required? I am afraid that I have too much data or that I should include UML as well?

[image: flow chart]

So which site is the most appropriate?

- [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/)
- [User Experience](//ux.stackexchange.com)
- [TeX - LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/)
- [Software Engineering](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (formerly known as Programmers)

Comment: What kind of feedback do you expect? We can't say if it is correct or not unless you're able to provide enough context, right?

Comment: @rene updated the question

Comment: It might be on-topic on [Software enigineering](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5321/questions-about-design-approach-and-technologies) but I would rather ask on their meta first as they are strict  and that question I linked to is from 2012. Also their [closed design questions](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdesign%5D+closed%3Ayes) could be of help to determine if yours would fit

Comment: @rene [posted it](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/8415/218283)

Comment: I would add the same detail you added here and not only link to this question. And both question could do with a small image if possible of your chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) has a number of questions on such [flowcharts](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flowcharts), so in general your question could (should?) be on topic there. A few existing example:

- [Proper symbol in a flow diagram for 'state'?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/42097/78128)
- [How do you document your interaction flows?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/14498/78128)
- [How to visualize a flowchart for the channels?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/30961/78128)

The only thing I would be wary of is: "I would like to get feedback". Review and critique (i.e. feedback) questions can be a bit of a strange fit for Stack Exchange sites, they're often open-ended and subjective and there is a close reason on UX specifically for this;

> Questions about Site Reviews are off-topic because questions here are expected to be relevant for a variety of people in the same situation. Reviewing a site, flow or interface only helps one person at a specific time. Instead try to ask a focused question about a particular aspect of the design that solicits solutions, not opinions.

So make sure to focus your question on a specific objective issue that is relevant to more than your specific case. Make sure to read through existing questions, read the relevant [help center](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [pages](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and ask on their [meta](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you're still unsure.